# Magento: how to show standard error/success message using JS in admin panel?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, magento, message

I can add error/success message to the Magento admin panel from server-side, for example,

```
Mage::getSingleton(’core/session’)->addError('***');
```

But how to show the same message on the client-side using JS? I mean standard way (of course I can create the same message box, but it's not a solution). For example when I need to show a status of some AJAX request. Any ideas?

Comment: if this is the answer, post it as "answer my own question", so other can see that it is answered

Comment: ooops, try again in 3 hours :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
function showMessage(txt, type) {
    var html = '<ul class="messages"><li class="'+type+'-msg"><ul><li>' + txt + '</li></ul></li></ul>';
    $('messages').update(html);
}
```

The *type* could be 'error', 'success', 'notice' or 'warning'. Enjoy!