# Custom module add to cart success message Magento

Tags: php, magento

In my custom module I want to show the add to cart success message. 
I have following piece of code in my .phtml file:

```
echo '<form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/'.$_product->getId().'/" method="get">'."\n";
$_attributes = $_product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray( $_product );
echo '<div class="product-attribute-options">'."\n";
$_child_products = Mage::getModel( 'catalog/product_type_configurable' )->getUsedProducts( null, $_product );
foreach( $_child_products as $_child_product ):
    if( $_child_product->isSaleable() ):
        $_child_product_qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct( $_child_product->getId() )->getQty();
        if( $_child_product_qty > 0 ):
            $_child_product_size_label = $_child_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size')->getFrontend()->getValue( $_child_product );
            $_child_product_size_val = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue( $_child_product->getId(), 'size', Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() );
            echo '<button value="'.$_child_product_size_val.'">'.$_child_product_size_label.'</button>'."\n";
        endif;
    endif;
endforeach;
echo '<input type="hidden" class="super_attribute_val" name="super_attribute[145]" value="" />'."\n";
echo '</div>'."\n";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="qty" value="1" />'."\n";
echo '<div class="add-to-cart">'."\n";
echo '<button class="button btn-cart"><span>'.$this->__('Buy Now').'</span></button>'."\n";
echo '</div>'."\n";
echo '</form>'."\n";
```

On pressing Buy Now, it adds the product to the cart but I want to show the green success message on top as well.

**EDITED**

I was advised to call the following function:

```
function showMessage(txt, type) {
    var html = '<ul class="messages"><li class="'+type+'-msg"><ul><li>' + txt + '</li></ul></li></ul>';
    $('messages').update(html);
}
```

But considering my form, I am not sure where to call this function from. I have:

```
echo '<button class="button btn-cart"><span>'.$this->__('Buy Now').'</span></button>'."\n";
```

and on pressing the button it submits the form with action get.

Comment: Magento does it on product page. I'm doing this in my custom module. It does add the file in to the cart and stays on the same page but doesn't show the success message. I'm not sure what line needs copying from product page, or extra code needs in.

Answer (score 1):

I think this code could help you:

```
Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addMessage("Your message");
```

Also, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6055324/1009697) could be interesting for you.

Maybe you need to use `$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();` in your template.

Comment: I think that this will not render if user is not signed in, but that should be verified.

Comment: It will render it. But as soon as the message has been display on one page, it's removed from the message queue.

Comment: I'm still lost... where should this go?

Comment: I think you don't need to use a javascipt. Just use `Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addMessage()` anywhere you want to place some message to the queue (controller, model, template may work to). And then place `$this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml();` in your template (.phtml) where you want to output a messages that was in a queue.

Comment: My form looks like this: <form action="/checkout/cart/add/product/'.$_product->getId().'/" method="get">. Where should I put Mage::getSingleton(‘customer/session’)->addMessage() so that it adds the message on button click?

Comment: I think there was a bit of misunderstanding about your problem from my side. Do you need to display that message when the product added to cart or when the button clicked? As an example you can check [this url](http://demo.magentocommerce.com/checkout/cart/add?product=52) where product added to cart via querystring and success message also displayed.

Comment: This form is in my custom module. On button click, it adds the product to the add and stays on the same custom page, which is fine. But from client point of view, they can't tell if product has been added to the cart or not so for that reason I want to show the message on the same page just to confirm that the action has been completed. Hope this explains a bit more.

Comment: You surely can achieve that by using javascript. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6055324/1009697) answer.

Comment: Looking at my form (in the question) how to call this function?
function showMessage(txt, type) {
    var html = '<ul class="messages"><li class="'+type+'-msg"><ul><li>' + txt + '</li></ul></li></ul>';
    $('messages').update(html);
}